# Enable TLS 1.2 Apache

Tags: apache, tls1.2, tls1.0

I want to enable TLS 1.2 in Ubuntu server 18.

I have edited the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`, adding

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

but still Apache is using tls 1.0. Is it possible to activate tls 1.2?

The Apache version is Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Aren't you missing `+TLSv1.2`?

Comment: @Álvaro González yes.

Answer (score 11):

To enable TLS 1.2 in Apache, you will need to change/add the `SSLProtocol` directive.

**Note:** To do any of this, mod_ssl should be enabled, if not, use the command `sudo a2enmod ssl`.

*The below configuration line will disable all TLS versions except TLSv1.2.*

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 #This makes Apache to support only TLSv1.2
```

You can also support TLSv1.3 if you have OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer. You can check the OpenSSL version by running the command: `openssl version` in the terminal, etc. You will also need Apache version 2.4.36 or more to use the TLSv1.3 provided by OpenSSL. You can also support TLSv1.3 together with TLSv1.2 using `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3`.

Comment: I ran command apachectl -M,->  ssl_module (shared),http_module (static), this are the modules I believe are linked with the command you said to run.
Also when I ran command : openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  
But when I change the ssl.conf, and added TLS 1.3, the apache didn't start

Comment: Run journalist -xe

Comment: See the output of that command. And see why Apache didn't start.

Comment: Thank for the reply,
here is the output of the command:

 AH00526: Syntax error on line 77 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:

 SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.3'
 Action 'start' failed.
 The Apache error log may have more information.
 apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Your Apache version doesn't support it. You will need Apache version 2.4.36 or higher.

Comment: Can I use TLS 1.2 instead?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: Can you please help me with this, activating tls 1.2 ?

Comment: Use the code in my answer, replace what you have used with that.

Comment: To enable TLS 1.2 in Apache, you will need to change/add the SSLProtocol directive. Use what I've given.

Comment: Change `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1` to `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2`

Comment: How to do this in the Apache installed in windows. Do we need to change the config/server.xml ?

Comment: @Sajeev are you using XAMPP?

Comment: @Exampleperson, No standalone Apache for Java

Comment: @Sajeev, Is [Apache JackRabbit](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/standalone-server.html) the server you are talking about?

Comment: @Exampleperson, No, I am running the Adempiere(java based application) on the Apache server, and it is installed on Windows server machine.

Comment: @Sajeev please let me know if there is a file called httpd.conf in the httpd/apache2/apache folder (or inside [nameofapache]/conf)

Comment: @Exampleperson There is no such file. I checked that. we have conf/server.xml is that the file we change the TLS version?

Comment: @Exampleperson The following is the code:   <!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
    <Connector
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="4444" maxThreads="200"
            scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
            keystoreFile="D:\Adempiere\keystore\myKeystore" keystorePass="myPassword"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

Comment: @Sajeev, I am pretty sure you are using Apache Tomcat. I cannot help you with that since I do not have any experience with it. I am sorry

Comment: hint, TLSv1.3 is not apache property, but it is property openssl version linked to apache. The simplest way to check it, is adding TLSv1.3 into config, and try full restart apache. If it will work, leave in this config. If not, revert config and restart apache again

Comment: @Znik, I might've misunderstood what you said, but anyways, when modifying OpenSSL configuration files, caution and attention are crucial. Creating backups of those files is essential to avoid disrupting the operating system due to improper changes. Editing Apache's configuration files poses lower risks. Thus, it's recommended to start with Apache when making configuration adjustments in such cases.

Comment: changing apache config file has no chance to disrupt OS. Of course, backing up everything what we modify, is very good practice. About apache, unfortunately not all versions have implementation for tls1.3 . I have this problem in Debian. At now it is not a big problem, because tls1.2 is still good. The same problem is on all other services based on SSL layer.